# Cron with sendmail incompatibility

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am trying to create a cron that every 2 days send the current space usage in an email to myself.

I can run the script perfectly and the email is sent but when I put it in the cronlist doesn't send the email.

The cron is active because I created a file that outputs the current date to a file and put it in the cronlist and it has been working.

This is my email script

```
#!/bin/bash
TOTAL=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $2}' )
USED=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $3}' )
AVAILABLE=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $4}' )
PERCENTAGE=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' )
EMAILSUBJECT="Server 79.XXX.XXX.XXX"
sendmail "admin@example.com" <<END
Subject: $EMAILSUBJECT

Disk usage on Server 79.XXX.XXX.XXX
Total space:       $TOTAL
Used space:        $USED
Available space:   $AVAILABLE
Percentage:        $PERCENTAGE
END
```

This is the test output for the crontab -l

```
[root@server ~]# crontab -l
0 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate ntp.blacknight.ie
0 21 * * * /bin/nice -n 10 /usr/local/directadmin/plugins/awstats/hooks/cgi-bin/updateall.sh
* * * * * bash /root/checkspace.sh
* * * * * bash /root/test.sh
```

The test.sh is the one that outputs the date, and the file is being filled.

The `checkspace.sh` sends the mail, and if I type `bash /root/checkspace.sh` in the command line the email is sent, but the cron doesn't work.

Is there any kind of incompatibility between the cron and the mail??

Comment: Give a good read to the "Debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info There little things that can make it work... or don't work!

Comment: It's likely sendmail isn't in the cron environment path.

Comment: cron jobs run with very minimal `$PATH` variables. Try extending `$PATH` in the script to include the location of `sendmail` or use a full path to `sendmail` and see if that works. (And as a side note there's no reason to use `grep` before `awk` in a pipeline as `awk` can do the filtering and you could format that entire output block in one `awk` command instead of four if you wanted to.)

Comment: Thanks Etan Reisner.
You got the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As commented above, there are many things that are likely to cause the problem. Probably, the need to set the full path in the commands you use.

From https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

> Common problems uncovered this way:
>
> ```
> foo: Command not found or just foo: not found.
> ```
>
> Most likely $PATH is set in your .bashrc or similar interactive init
>   file. Try specifying all commands by full path (or put source
>   ~/.bashrc at the start of the script you're trying to run).

---

Also, I want to indicate another way to do this block of code:

```
TOTAL=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $2}' )
USED=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $3}' )
AVAILABLE=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $4}' )
PERCENTAGE=$(df / -h | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' )
```

Note that you are calling `df -h /` four times, while one suffices:

```
read _ TOTAL USED AVAILABLE PERCENTAGE _ < <(df -hP / | tail -1)
```

Where `tail -1` is used to remove the header. `sed '/Filesystem/d'` could also be used.

Or if you want to use a line for each one of them, do:

```
TOTAL=$(df / -hP | awk '/\// { print $2}' )
                                ^^^^
                                filter lines containing /
```

Note the usage of `-P` in `df`, that stands for `P`ortability (or `--portability`, "use the POSIX output format"), used to prevent lines being split if they are too long. [Thanks to Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725043/cron-with-sendmail-incompatibility#comment40217748_25725168) for this.

Comment: You left the `grep` in that last example. Also `df -h` will split lines if the filesystem label is too long so you want `-P/--portability` to prevent that.

Comment: Ops, I missed the `grep` there, true. Also, thanks for the `-P` option, indeed it makes the output more easy to work with. Updated accordingly, many thanks!

Comment: @glennjackman yes, I promote as much as I can. [that other guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) created a great reference there (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7086085/revisions).